# Horizontal centering of a div can be done by margin-left and right auto, together with a width, or max-width, but not min-width?

Tags: css

In the old days before having `max-width` and `min-width`, we have to set the `width` to some value other than `auto`, together with `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`, for the `div` to be horizontally centered.

**Now that we have `max-width` and `min-width`, we can also set the `max-width` to some value other than `none` to horizontally centered it? Is there any spec for it?**

P.S. `min-width` won't work as the `div` will span the whole width, so you can consider it horizontally centered, except that the left and right margin are both `0`, so there is no horizontally centering effect.

Example:

`width`:     https://jsfiddle.net/dtr7t4z7/1/
`max-width`: https://jsfiddle.net/dtr7t4z7/2/ and https://jsfiddle.net/dtr7t4z7/3/
`min-width`: https://jsfiddle.net/dtr7t4z7/4/

Answer (score 1):

`margin: auto` will just fill the remaining space equally on both sides.  If a `width` or `max-width` are not specified, a div will take up as much horizontal space as possible. Because the div is the full width of its container when only `min-width` is specified, there isn't any space left for `margin: auto` to distribute.

Comment: ok... I always knew `width` can do it (the horizontal centering). Wasn't too sure about anything else... so `max-width` can do it too

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ehnvy1xz/5/

```
body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
#line {
  text-align:center;
  background: yellow;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

If you really need the min-width. I would recommend using flex on the parent div and centering it that way instead.

Comment: so this is flexbox huh? I learned some of it except if it is not supported by IE 10, then I stopped learning / using it for now... kind of waiting the drop of IE 10 by the industry

Comment: It makes everything so easy though. It partially works in IE 10/11, you just need to make some modifications for IE sometimes.

Comment: modifications for IE was such a headache in my past jobs. I would rather use a solution good for all modern browsers.